# Is multiline meta content value allowed?

Tags: html, meta-tags, multiline, meta, content-security-policy

I am using the `meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` tag to whitelist domains. The list is getting quite big so I was wondering is it ok to use new lines in the `content` value?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
   default-src 'self' http://example.com;
   style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://example.com;
   script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://example.com;
">
```

**EDIT:** just found that `validator.w3.org` shows error on multiline `content` value, so I guess it's not allowed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maintainer of the [W3C HTML Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) (aka validator) here. The HTML checker doesn’t report errors for multi-line `content` values. The error that it reports for your example above is this:

```
Bad value Content-Security-Policy for attribute http-equiv on element meta
```

That is, the error is for the **`http-equiv`** attribute, not for the `content` attribute.

But try changing your source to this:

```
<meta name="Content-Security-Policy" content="
   default-src 'self' http://example.com;
   style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://example.com;
   script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://example.com;
">
```

…and you’ll see that it reports no error for that.

So, the error you’re seeing is because: If the `meta` element has a `http-equiv` attribute, then [according to the HTML spec the value of the `http-equiv` must be one of the following](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#pragma-directives):

- `content-type`
- `default-style`
- `refresh`
- `X-UA-Compatible`

So the HTML spec doesn’t (yet) allow `http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"`.

All that said, this **is a bug in the W3C HTML checker**, because the checker **should** support `http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy`, following the [details provided about `http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy` in the Content Security Policy spec](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/CSP2/#delivery-html-meta-element).

So I [raised a checker bug for it](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/153) just now.

This is basically **also a bug in the HTML spec**, because at this point the HTML spec itself should also say that `http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` is allowed. So [I’ve raised a bug against the HTML spec for this](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/88) to add `http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` to the [Pragma directives](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#pragma-directives) section of the HTML spec that I cited above, and a patch for that’ll likely be getting merged into the spec later this week.

Comment: so can we trust W3C HTML checker on that part where it says that multiline `content` value is ok?

Comment: @untitled a multiline `content` value isn’t allowed in all cases, but per the spec it is allowed when the element has a `name` attribute, and you can trust that the HTML checker conforms to the spec on that.